# Problem setting up persisted permissions for mid-level roles

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, types, casl

I've been exploring CASL for managing persisted permissions. But I am stuck on assigning permissions to roles such as team managers and department heads, who are more mid-level employees. So far I have:

```
const roles = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "admin", // Has access to everything
    permissions: JSON.stringify([{ action: "manage", subject: "all" }]),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "manager", // Has access to people who they directly manage and anyone below them
    permissions: JSON.stringify([
      {
        action: "manage", //direct employee under user
        subject: "Order",
        conditions: { "owner.managerId": "{{user._id}}" },
      },
      {
        action: "manage", // his own orders
        subject: "Order",
        conditions: { "owner._id": "{{user._id}}" },
      },


    ]),
  },
];
```

I can give permissions to direct employees that work under a manager, but not indirect employees that work under employees he/she manages. Think tree-model

I can give permissions to direct employees that work under a manager, but not indirect employees that work under employees he/she manages. Think tree-model